# Finding characters before a word in a string

Tags: ruby, string, match

I have data pulled from an xlsx file that look like this:

```
[6, 2]=>"Comment", [6, 3]=>"Complaint", [6, 4]=>"Enquiry"
```

I want to search the array and return the value of the second number in the brackets before. I.e., searching for `Complaint` should return `3`. Any help is appreciated.

**NB** - Updated in light on comments to array. Removed string conversion in OP.

```
require 'roo'

today_file=(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/output/today-report.xlsx')

def by_value(data, value)
  found = data.find do |k, v|
    v == value
  end

  found and found[0][1]
end

data = Roo::Excelx.new (today_file)

output = by_value(data, "Complaint").inspect

puts output
```

When run this returns 'nil'

The output of the array from this is in this form:

```
{[1, 1]=>"YESTERDAY - 02/10/14", [1, 4]=>"Another comment below the fold - scroll down", [2, 1]=>"Yesterday we received 11 regarding the service.", [4, 1]=>"TYPE", [6, 1]=>"", [6, 2]=>"Comment", [6, 3]=>"Complaint", [6, 4]=>"Enquiry", [6, 5]=>"Total (Type)", [7, 1]=>"Editorial and other queries", [7, 2]=>1.0, [7, 3]=>7.0,...}
```

Comment: Is that data a Hash, or a big formatted string?

Comment: Is that literally how you have your data structured? A hash with array objects as keys? If so, that would make it easy... something like: `data.key(string)[1]` if `data` is that structure and `string` is the string you're looking for.

Comment: It could be a hash very easily if it makes it easier. It's currently a hash converted to a string.

Comment: Converting something to a string is usually very counter-productive. Keep it in some kind of Ruby data structure for as long as possible.

Comment: @MattVisser If I paste in that data, minus the `...` part, and run it, I get `3`.

Comment: Would appear the problem lies in that the variable type (in the original code) is Roo::Excelx. Hence why the code doesn't recognise it as a hash. Needs to be converted to hash before this will work. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a strange requirement. Here is how to do it.

```
word = "Complaint"
data_string[/, (\d+)\]=>"#{Regexp.escape(word)}"/, 1] # => "3"
```

Comment: Clever and terrifying. This is, hopefully, a last resort. To be a general-purpose solution, don't forget to escape the `word` value being substituted in there with [`Regexp.escape`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Regexp.html#method-c-escape).

Comment: There's also the problem of how to handle things like searching for `Annoying "String"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to Ruby, you'll want to spend time familiarizing yourself with the [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Enumerable.html) library. It's got a ton of tools for manipulating and extracting data.

In this case, `find` does the job:

```
def by_value(data, value)
  # Find the key/value pair where the value matches
  found = data.find do |k, v|
    v == value
  end

  # If one of these was found, pull the second number from the key
  found and found[0][1]
end

data = {[6, 2]=>"Comment", [6, 3]=>"Complaint", [6, 4]=>"Enquiry"}

puts by_value(data, "Complaint").inspect
# => 3
```

It's worth noting that this is a relatively slow operation since you're doing a linear search. If this is done frequently enough you'd want to invert it so searching is faster:

```
def by_value(data, value)
  found = data[value]

  found and found[1]
end

# Using Hash#invert switches the keys and values so you can now look-up by value
data = {[6, 2]=>"Comment", [6, 3]=>"Complaint", [6, 4]=>"Enquiry"}.invert

puts by_value(data, "Complaint").inspect
# => 3
```

Comment: Why the default `found[0][1]` one ?

Comment: Ahh! Feeling sleepy.. so :-)

Comment: Thanks, it appears to work with the smaller amount of data - so I'm assuming there is something wrong elsewhere which I can work on. Would appear puts data is flushing what I expect, so not entirely sure.

Comment: @MattVisser If you have another sample of the data you're searching, provide it if you can.

Comment: Is the output of an xlsx file via Roo - will add to. Will add to top.